# ¿Que hace el navegador si aplico left: 0 y right: 0 en un elemento posicionado?

Tags: css, css3

`right: 0;` y `left: 0;` están como que en conflicto.

¿Como determina el navegador la posición final que tomara horizontalmente el elemento?

Al final el valor que gana es el de `left:0;` pero ¿se tiene alguna explicación de porque es así?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

  <div style="width:50px; height:50px; background: pink; position: fixed; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0;">
    
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left):

> Cuando se definen tanto `left` como `right`, y las restricciones de ancho no lo impiden, el elemento se estirará para satisfacer ambas.
>
> Si el elemento no puede estirarse para satisfacer ambos, *la posición del elemento está sobre especificada*. Cuando este es el caso, **el valor `left` tiene prioridad cuando el contenedor está de [`izquierda a derecha`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#direction)**; el `right` tiene prioridad cuando el contenedor es de `derecha a izquierda`.

---

#### Mas info

- [CSS Level 2 (Revision 1)](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-left)
- [CSS Positioned Layout Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-3/#rel-pos) (*Working Draft*)

Answer (score 1):

**Espero ser de ayuda, saludos**

Estas propiedades permiten definir el desplazamiento de la posición de un elemento respecto a un origen de coordenadas y el origen de coordenadas que se toma, y los únicos valores que acepta son relativo y absoluto.

Posición relative: Definen cuánto se desplaza el elemento respecto a lo que sería su posición normal.

Posición absolute o fixed: Definen cuánto se desplaza el elemento respecto a las coordenadas de origen.

No tiene sentido utilizar top y bottom al mismo tiempo, porque sería decir que el elemento sube y baja. Hay que utilizar sólo una de estas dos propiedades. Lo mismo para right y left.